# Networkx convert graph to tree preserving edge data

Tags: python-3.x, networkx, graph-theory

I have a undirect Graph G containing edge data (a dict). I can see its data with `G.edges.data()`.

I can convert my graph to a tree using `networkx.dfs_tree(G)` the problem is the edge data is lost.

Is it possible to make this conversion preserving the data?

Comment: undirected, perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found myself.

Create a undirect Graph that preserves the data (duplicated edges). Then get its edge data attributes creating a dictionary. Use that with `nx.set_edge_attributes`. Nonexistent edges are ignored per networkx docs.

```
import networkx as nx 

Gd = nx.DiGraph(G) 
data = { (u, v) : d for u, v, d in Gd.edges.data() }  # create a dict of { edge : data ...}
Gdt = nx.dfs_tree(Gd) # create tree
nx.set_edge_attributes(Gdt, data) # set all tree edge data at once
```